# Array undefined from Fetch API

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch-api

I can access the array `words` in global scope but when I try to find an item by typing `words[index]` , it returns undefined. How can I solve this?

```
let words = [];

    function fetchWords() {
  fetch("https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php")  
    .then((res) => res.json())   
    .then((data) => {  
      for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) {   
        words.push(data.categories[i].strCategory);
      }
    });
}

fetchWords();`
console.log(words); //This works   
console.log(words[2]); // But this does not. Why?
```

Comment: Also of interest: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086). The reason why the first "works" is described here: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440). In short, you just log the reference to the array, but when you expand it in the console, you get the state of said array at the time you expand it, not at the time the log was made.

Comment: does data.categories[2].strCategory exist?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you call:

`console.log(words[2]);`

before you fetch the result. You need to await `fetchWords` before `console.log(words[2]);`